# Jasper Report con JRBeanCollectionDataSource error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

Estoy intentado ejecutar un Jasper Report dentro de una Aplicación Java con JSF.

Al invocar la creación del Jasper Report con un DataSource, que es una colleción de JavaBeans (JRBeanCollectionDataSource), me da un error al ejecutar:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
```

El *dataSource* se crea con:

```
Collection<SlaReportItem> slaItems =  new ArrayList<SlaReportItem>(reports.get(0).getItems());
final JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(slaItems);
```

El error es:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel
>        at >java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
>        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
>        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
>        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
>        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
>        at >net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName
> ```

Da la impresión que al crear el Report no encuentra las clases que configurar el DataSource.

Si alguien tiene ha tenido que pelear con algo parecido, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Antes de llamar a `fillReport()` ¿qué te regresa `dataSource.getRecordCount();`?

Comment: Gracias @Sal. Lo consulte y el dataSource tiene registros. Para la prueba tiene 2.

Comment: Entonces tendremos que revisar la configuración, que dependerá de tu entorno: desarrollo (IDE) o publicado, SO, servidor de aplicación, versiones, WAR o EAR, application.xml, module.xml, manifest.mf, etc. por mencionar algunos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema finalmente era que la versión del jasper reports del JasperStudio era diferente de la versión que utilizaba en la aplicación.

En la applicación tenía la 6.12 y en el JasperStudio la 6.17.

Al utilizar el subreport compilado, daba la excepción de ClassNotFound.